# We have applied for Microsoft Non For Profit program and we received credits. How to apply the credits to Azure?

Tags: azure

We have applied for Microsoft Non For Profit program and we received credits.

How to apply the credits to Azure?

I have a new account with access to a fresh portal.azure.com. I haven't created any subscription yet because I don't want to cause any confusion nor use a credit card if unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue. We were given non-profit status, but when I logged in to the non-profit portal (https://nonprofit.microsoft.com/), Azure offer was not available among other offerings (Office365, Linkedin for nonprofits, Github for nonprofits, Training for nonprofits). I contacted Microsoft support and they sent me this link that I used to create a free Azure subscription:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0036p/